# How to retrieve NetSuite SalesOrder Related Records (of type Item Fulfillment) using Mulesoft /Java?

Tags: mule, netsuite, dataweave, mulesoft

Currently I'm using mulesoft to retrieve Sales Order , but i want to return related records of type "Item Fulfillment" . I'm using below dataweave and netsuite operation search "Transaction". below is the dw code:

```
 %dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    basic: {
        customFieldList: {
            customField: [{
                scriptId: "custbody_order_type",
                searchValue: "Promo Opportunity",
                operator: "IS"
            } as Object {
                    class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.SearchStringCustomField"
                },
                {
                scriptId: "custbody_promo_reason",
                searchValue: "Exchange",
                operator: "CONTAINS"
            } as Object {
                    class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.SearchStringCustomField"
                }
            ]
        },
        lastModifiedDate: {
            operator: "AFTER",
            searchValue: "2020-04-10T00:00:00" as LocalDateTime
        },
        recordType: {
            operator: "IS",
            searchValue: "SALESORDER"
        }

    }
} as Object {
    class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.TransactionSearch"
}
```

Not sure how to add the condition to get related records , can someone help me ?